# CRM 2011 - JavaScript don't update fields

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have a basic calculation on javascipt. It calculates true and changes the field's value with true value. But when I check it on database, it shows me ex-value of a field.
I use

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_exchangerate").fireOnChange();
```

on formOnLoad.
My actual code;

```
function ExchangeRateOnChange() {
    var exchangeRate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_exchangerate").getValue();
    if (!exchangeRate) {
        exchangeRate = 1;
    }
    var saleAmount = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_saleamount").getValue();
    if (saleAmount) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_saleamounttl").setValue(saleAmount * exchangeRate);
        // Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_saleamounttl").setSubmitMode("always");
        // I used setSubmit, but it won't worked too
    }
}
```

Comment: field type of "new_exchangerate1","new_saleamount" and "new_saleamounttl"?

Answer (score 1):

In case you field is disabled on a form changes would not be sent to CRM Endpoints. To make it work try to add following after you've set value:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_saleamounttl").setSubmitMode("always");
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was: `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_exchangerate").addOnChange(this.ExchangeRateOnChange);`
Because calling `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_exchangerate").fireOnChange();` doesn't call your method. But you said that it has calculate fields.

You can try to call `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_saleamounttl").fireOnChange();`after you change field.